# What is the shortcut to run single sql in IBM Data Studio (Equivalent of F9 in Toad)

Tags: ibm-data-studio

I am new to IBM Datastudio (DB2) and my experience is on sql Developer and Toad.
I tried F5, it runs all the sqls, but i would like to run one specific sql only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the particular sql statement and then press F5 that will executed the selected sql only.

If you just want basic sql execution functionality you can also use sql developer with db2 java driver. Steps are discussed https://community.oracle.com/thread/556323?start=15&tstart=0